# how do i set php_value on .htaccess based on host name?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, wamp

In my web server I have added some line in .htaccess to set php_value. The .htaccess code are given below:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\prevalue.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\prevalue.php'
</IfModule>
```

How could I do this for specific host like (xyz.com)

**Please advice me**

Comment: Are you getting internal server error message, when using php_value ?

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but you could use an `if` with `HTTP_HOST`:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'xyz.com'">
    php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\prevalue.php'
</If>
<Else>
    php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\otherprevalue.php'
</Else>
```

Or:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'xyz.com'">
    php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\prevalue.php'
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'abc.com'">
    php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\otherprevalue.php'
</If>
```

There is a [Variables Cheatsheet](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet/).

Comment: IT works. Thank you. My final script is : 
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
 <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'laptop.appsbd.com'">
  php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\prevalue.php'
 </If>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
 <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'laptop.appsbd.com'">
  php_value auto_prepend_file '\var\prevalue.php'
 </If> 
</IfModule>